# Action Bar Items are clickable, but do not respond to events in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Basically my project have to have different toolbars, one for each fragment switched by the bottom navigation bar.
The fragment toolbars items are clickable, when I long press,  shows the title item etc, but they don't perform the action. For example, When I set to show a toast when click on that item, he'll not perform. Any Suggestion? Thanks.

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "Tag Free";

    DialogFragment mDialog;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    RevealFrameLayout reveal;
    FrameLayout frame;
    private ConstraintLayout layoutDialog;
    boolean isOpen = false;

    public FeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

        /** Toolbar **/
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        ActionBar ab = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        // navigation bottom
        fab = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_button);
        fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pencil_black_24dp));
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.hold, R.anim.slide_down);
            Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
            if (prev != null) {
                ft.remove(prev);
            }
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new PostDialog();
            dialogFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
            dialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogFragmentTheme);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.appbar_feed, menu);super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_personProfile:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"not responding",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyUserProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

            case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"not responding",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;


            default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are not chaining to the superclass in the activity methods.**

Refactor your code as below :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.appbar_feed, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_personProfile:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"not responding",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyUserProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"not responding",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break; 


        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            break; 

    }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope now your code will work fine.

Comment: Still don't work with edit. Maybe is something on my Activity, no?

Comment: Can you log some to see in log is that triggering or not. let me know .

Comment: Can you debug is  item.getItemId() for your specific switch case.

Comment: I have done it, look at the log https://prnt.sc/kft95b is Always The Default Option.